# QT5.9.1 In-App Purchase vs. Apple App Store on macOS

Tags: macos, qt, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have spent now the whole Sunday without any success on the following issue:
I have an app for macOS made with Qt 5.9.1 and it was available in Apple's App Store for a year. Now I want to add an In-App purchase. I exactly followed the instructions given in the QT documentation regarding registering the product in iTunesConnect. There everything looks fine. Then I copied the C++ code from the QT doc into my project and changed the product id. But whenever if call product->purchase() in MyApplication::purchaseHealthPotion() the app crashes because the pointer product is NULL. (I am using here the naming of the QT example). To my feeling the program does not build up a connection to App Store. I am even not requested to log in with a test account as the docs are saying.
Thus, it seems that the purchasing module is not working at all.
Did anybody ever made it working on macOS and can help me a little bit?
Please note, the example code by QT is the same for QT5.9.1 and QT5.11.0. I am now upgrading to Qt5.11.0 just to be sure.

Edit: Upgrading to 5.11.0 did not solve it.

Raphael

Comment: Check if the purchaising module has error signals of methods you can use to get error messages. Otherwise try debugging. You can try to build the actual example itself and check if that works